# Left Join gives me a lot of duplicate value

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables.there are 3 common columns. When I use left join it gives me a lot duplicate values. How  should I avoid the duplicate.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details about the problem you are facing?  Your table schemas and your SQL statements would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use left join as below:

For Example:

```
SELECT
   cu.Id
   ,cu.CustomerName,
   _ord.Total

FROM Customers cu
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT
   customerId
   ,sum(amount) Total
   FROM Orders
   GROUP BY customerId
) _ord on _ord.customerId=cu.id
```

Comment: @ Hesam, how to remove duplicate records in big query in general. Can i use row_num clause to do it? Please give me hint in detail.

Comment: I think it's better you first, show your query and duplicated result and also the expected result